# A Sql Query for Looking up International numbers from WHMCS into PBX

Tags: mysql, sql, freepbx

I am trying to integrate my WHMCS and PBX together, which i can do via mysql.

The problem is WHMCS now stores phone numbers as +44.000 000 0000 and my PBX creates the query as 07000000000 (without spaces)

I had the idea of the following, but unfortunately doesn't look at the new replaced numbers with no spaces

```
(SELECT  REPLACE(phonenumber, ' ', '') FROM tblclients) UNION
(SELECT companyname AS name FROM tblclients WHERE phonenumber LIKE "%xxx xxx xxxx%") UNION
(SELECT companyname AS name FROM tblcontacts WHERE phonenumber LIKE "%xxx xxx xxxx%")
```

The actual SQL Query that goes into the the PBX is for example

```
(SELECT firstname AS name FROM tblclients WHERE phonenumber LIKE ‘%[NUMBER]%’) UNION 
(SELECT firstname AS name FROM tblcontacts WHERE phonenumber LIKE ‘%[NUMBER]%’)
```

Apologies not the best at SQL queries, just looking how I can do this in a single query, as FreePBX only allows a single query, in its request.

The international phone number, for example, is +44.161 872 0248

I need it to be +44.1618720248 - I just need to remove the spaces and zero off the front of the incoming number on the PBX.

e.g. WHMCS database stored data is +44.161 872 0248

The PBX outputs the incoming number, [NUMBER] to 01618720248 - so a LIKE statement won't work As the LIKE statement would look like (LIKE "%01618720248%) not the same as whats in WHMCS database.

So my main question is how do we remove the 0 from the PBX [NUMBER] and then remove the spaces out of the data that is returned from the query?

Comment: Sample data from both systems and desired results overall would help.

Comment: International phone number for example is +44.161 872 0248 i need it to be +44.1618720248 - I just need to remove the spaces and zero off the front of the incoming number on the PBX. for example


WHMCS is +44.161 872 0248 but PBX replaces [PHONE} with 01618720248 - so a LIKE statement won't work

As the LIKE statement would look like (LIKE "%01618720248%) not the same as whats in WHMCS

Answer (score -1):

You can create view and give pbx access to view.

You also can change sql in pbx to be any one.